# whole number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get 28.6813276578 when i multiply 2 numbers a and b, how can i make it whole number with less digits

and also, when i multiply again i get results after first reult like 28.681321405.4428.68 how to get only one result ?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#total").hide();
    $("#form1").submit(function(){

    var a = parseFloat($("#user_price").val());
    var b = parseFloat($("#selling").val());
    var total = a*b; 



    $("#total").append(total)
    .show('slow')
    .css({"background":"yellow","font-size":50})
    ;
    return false;   
    });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do several things:

```
total = total.toFixed([number of decimals]);
total = Math.round(total);
total = parseInt(total);
```

1. `toFixed()` will round your number to the number of decimals indicated.
2. `Math.round()` will round numbers to the nearest integer.
3. `parseInt()` will take a string and attempt to parse an integer from it without rounding. `parseInt()` is a little trickier though, in that it will parse the first characters in a string that are numbers until they are not, meaning `parseInt('123g32ksj')` will return `123`, whereas `parseInt('sdjgg123')` will return `NaN`.

   - For the sake of completeness, `parseInt()` accepts a second parameter which can be used to express the base you're trying to extract with, meaning that, for instance,
     `parseInt('A', 16) === 10` if you were trying to parse a hexidecimal.

Comment: `toFixed` **rounds** to the decimals provided (or 0 decimals when parameter is missing which makes it identical to `round`). It doesn't just truncate as you say. You should correct your answer. But I gave you a +1 one anyway because you mention both functions. Actually `toFixed` will also append missing zeros when required.

Comment: how to stop next answer appearing in the same div on and on if i don't refresh page ?

Comment: For more completeness: `parseInt` without a specified base works the same way as JavaScript's syntax, so `parseInt("080")` will be parsed as octal and return `10`. For this reason it is recommended to usually specify a base.

Answer (score 2):

See `Math.round(...)`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers about rounding, you are appending the answer to "total" by using

```
$("#total").append(total)
```

You need to replace the previous text rather than appending by using

```
$("#total").html(total)
```